# Change position fixed of div if scroll

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I tried to fix a div after scroll on vuejs; My code like this :

```
...
async created() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.calendarScroll);
}
methods: {
    calendarScroll() {
    console.log('Scroll');
    const dateHeader = document.querySelector('.dates-header');
    if (dateHeader) {
      if (window.scrollTop() >= 200) {
        dateHeader.style.top = 0;
        dateHeader.style.position = 'fixed';
      }
    }
  },
}
```

the error is : `Calendar.vue?404a:681 Uncaught TypeError: window.scrollTop is not a function`

Comment: Why not use [sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky_positioning)?

Comment: Use `window.scrollY` to get the actual vertical scroll point. `window.scrollTop()` does not exist on the `window` object (unless you define it)

Comment: @t.niese Actually window has no scrollTop prop. You can use `Element.scrollTop` to get some element's vertical scroll position. `window.scrollTop >= 200` will be always `false` since `window.scrollTop` is `undefined`. For the window object, the equivalent is `window.scrollY`.

Comment: @Doc yes that's true. Is should have been [`window.scrollY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY)

Answer (score -1):

You can add `scrollTo` to the Element prototype before you mount:

```
Element.prototype.scrollTo = () => {}
```

All Elements created after you add this code will have the `scrollTo` method.
For more detail, you can check this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/319#issuecomment-354667621

Comment: The question is not about `scrollTo` but `scrollTop`

Comment: But the root cause, which is stopping the execution is the vue.js error related to the scrollTo() method.